# Add json object into http request as body in vb.net

Tags: json, vb.net, rest, httprequest

I've one API in vb.net and i want to make HTTP request to another API from one of my methods. I've created an instance of WebClient class and added my headers but the problem is i could not add my json object as body into HTTP request. Here is my code.

```
            Dim webc As New WebClient

            webc.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/json")
            webc.Headers.Add("Authorization: " + testHeader)
            webc.Headers("x-iyzi-rnd") = random_string

            Dim url = "https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com/"

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

            Dim html As Byte() = webc.DownloadData(url)
            Dim utf As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
            Dim response As String = utf.GetString(html)
```

Comment: You might find you're better off using an HTTPClient rather than a WebClient

Comment: Actually i've tired a few different classes to make Http Request but i could not find any solution till now so that i wanted to share my last code, thanks for advice by the way